# How to monitor Solaris network interface bandwidth?

Tags: networking, performance, solaris

I would like to see x MB/s, like freebsd has ifstat command which is pretty cool. I need something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [BWMng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bwmng/) for real-time monitoring, but I can live with SNMP-based graphing and reporting through munin or cricket.

On a side note, I understand that ifstat itself can be compiled for Solaris.

Oh, for throughout, detailed, protocol-level statistic dissections, [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/overview.html) can't be beaten, but it requires a lot of resources and is overkill for most cases.

Comment: Thanks, i found this only: 

 dladm show-link -s -i 10 bge1

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the "raw" kernel stats using kstat:

kstat -p -m ce (or whatever you interface is e.g. bg)

Answer (score 0):

One of the nicest tools that I've found is [nicstat](http://www.brendangregg.com/Perf/network.html).  It helped me to quickly rule-out the network when we were trying to diagnose what we believed to be an NFS problem related to the network.